# how to put ng-show conditions in a function in .js file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to validate a webpage where the inputs will be alphanumeric, max-length is 45 and unique. Here is the code. Is there any way that I could put all these three ng-show conditions in one function in my controller.js (something like $scope.showError ()) and only call that function in ng-show here

```
form name="addFieldForm"
        .w-100
          .pv3.w-100.w-two-thirds-ns
            label What type of field would you like to add to your input?
            select name="type" ng-model="field.type.value" ng-options="type.value as type.label for type in types" ng-change="valid('type')"
        .w-100
          .pv2.w-100.w-two-thirds-ns ng-if="field.type.value === 'input'" ng-class="{ 'b--red' : addFieldForm.lt.$touched && addFieldForm.lt.$error.required }"
            label.db Input
            input type="text" name="lt" ng-model="field.label.value" ng-maxLength="45" placeholder="Enter Input" ng-change="valid('label')" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9 -]*$/" required=""
          div ng-show="addFieldForm.lt.$touched"
            p.fw6.t-red.pt2.mb0 ng-show="addFieldForm.lt.$error.required || addFieldForm.lt.$error.maxlength" Input is required and must not exceed 45 characters.
            p.fw6.t-red.pt2.mb0 ng-show="!addFieldForm.lt.$error.required && !addFieldForm.lt.$error.maxlength && addFieldForm.lt.$error.pattern" Input is invalid.
            p.fw6.t-red.pt2.mb0 ng-show="!addFieldForm.lt.$error.required && !addFieldForm.lt.$error.maxlength && !addFieldForm.lt.$error.pattern" ng-if="!validate" Input needs to be unique.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make something like below. Make a function inside JS and call that function in `ng-change="showError()"`.

**IN JS**

```
$scope.showError() {

    if ($scope.addFieldForm.lt.$error.required || $scope.addFieldForm.lt.$error.maxlength) {

        $scope.inputIsRequired = true;

    }

if (!$scope.addFieldForm.lt.$error.required && !$scope.addFieldForm.lt.$error.maxlength && $scope.addFieldForm.lt.$error.pattern) {

        $scope.InputIsInvalid = true;

    }

if (!$scope.addFieldForm.lt.$error.required && !$scope.addFieldForm.lt.$error.maxlength && !$scope.addFieldForm.lt.$error.pattern && !validate) {

        $scope.InputIsUnique = true;

    }
```

**IN VIEW::**

```
<span ng-show="inputIsRequired"> Input is required and must not exceed 45 characters.<span>
<span ng-show="InputIsInvalid">Input is invalid.<span>
<span ng-show="InputIsUnique">Input needs to be unique.<span>
```